# Eclipse-Luna TCP/IP Monitor config Import/Export

Tags: eclipse, monitoring

I have an small problem in my working environment. For every new version of software, we need to create new workspace (not ask why..), first we use monitor TCP/IP with eclipse-luna. Every time, we must recreate the monitor.

How could i import/export config of Monitor ? it's really tired because we have many backend.

He could be very useful for my team because we use an common .properties (contains all adress) which each developper change for doing monitoring. If we have been able to have an export/import monitor  TCP/Ip, it's will be more easy to do accept to create another file which will be delegate to monitoring.

It's an old project and many thing could be do on for upgrade developing environment..

Answer (score 0):

You can try exporting preferences in your older workspace:

```
Right Click in explorer > Export > Preferences
```

Then when in your new workspace :

```
Right Click in explorer > Import > Preferences > select the file you just exported
```

Not sure if your properties will be there...